# Sort by column within multi index level in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a sorting request per example below.

Do i need to reset_index(), then sort() and then set_index() or is there a slick way to do this?

```
l = [[1,'A',99],[1,'B',102],[1,'C',105],[1,'D',97],[2,'A',19],[2,'B',14],[2,'C',10],[2,'D',17]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns = ['idx1','idx2','col1'])
df.set_index(['idx1','idx2'],inplace=True)

# assume data has been received like this...
print df

           col1
idx1 idx2      
1    A       99
     B      102
     C      105
     D       97
2    A       19
     B       14
     C       10
     D       17

# I'd like to sort descending on col1, partitioning within index level = 'idx2'

           col1
idx1 idx2      
1    C      105
     B      102
     A       99
     D       97

2    A       19
     D       17
     B       14
     C       10
```

---

Thank you for the answer
Note I change the data slightly:

```
l = [[1,'A',99],[1,'B',11],[1,'C',105],[1,'D',97],[2,'A',19],[2,'B',14],[2,'C',10],[2,'D',17]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns = ['idx1','idx2','col1'])
df.set_index(['idx1','idx2'],inplace=True)
df = df.sort_index(by='col1', ascending=False)
```

however the output is

```
idx1 idx2      
1    C      105
     A       99
     D       97
2    A       19
     D       17
     B       14
1    B       11
2    C       10
```

i would have wanted it to be

```
idx1 idx2      
1    C      105
     A       99
     D       97
     B       11

2    A       19
     D       17
     B       14
     C       10
```

Comment: The editing of this question is actually very confusing, partially b/c the answers use the top df and not the bottom df.  It may be too late now, but the top df should have been deleted so everyone would know to use the bottom df.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use `sort_index`:

```
 df.sort_index(level='col1', ascending=False)
```

Before version 0.17 `level` was `by`:

```
df.sort_index(by='col1', ascending=False)
```

This outputs:

```
             col1
idx1    idx2    
1       C    105
        B    102
        A    99
        D    97
2       A    19
        D    17
        B    14
        C    10
```

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to sort by an index level and a column at the same time.

Comment: ok no worries. I can .reset_index(), then carry out a regular sort on cols {idx1 ascending, col1 descending} and then .set_index(['idx1','idx2'])

Comment: sort_index() using the `by` argument is now deprecated. How does that affect this answer?

Comment: @zthomas.nc  I don't think this answer worked on the edited data.  It worked on the original question, but only b/c all col1 values for idx=1 were greater than all col1 values for idx=2

Answer (score 22):

You need [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)::

```
l = [[1,'A',99],[1,'B',11],[1,'C',105],[1,'D',97],
     [2,'A',19],[2,'B',14],[2,'C',10],[2,'D',17]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns = ['idx1','idx2','col1'])
df.set_index(['idx1','idx2'],inplace=True)
print (df)
           col1
idx1 idx2      
1    A       99
     B       11
     C      105
     D       97
2    A       19
     B       14
     C       10
     D       17

df = df.reset_index() \
       .sort_values(['idx1','col1'], ascending=[True,False]) \
       .set_index(['idx1','idx2'])
print (df)
           col1
idx1 idx2      
1    C      105
     A       99
     D       97
     B       11
2    A       19
     D       17
     B       14
     C       10
```

EDIT:

For version `0.23.0` is possible use [columns and index levels together](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#sorting-by-a-combination-of-columns-and-index-levels) (but buggy now if use `ascending=[True, False]`, so maybe in newer versions):

```
df = df.sort_values(['idx1','col1'], ascending=[True,False])
print (df)

           col1
idx1 idx2      
1    C      105
     A       99
     D       97
     B       11
2    A       19
     D       17
     B       14
     C       10
```

Comment: @JohnE - You are right, so I remove first solutiom.

Answer (score 9):

This first sorts by the desired column, the resorts on the idx1 MultiIndex level only and works in up to date pandas versions that deprecate the `by` kwarg.

```
df.sort_values('col1', ascending=False).sort_index(level='idx1', sort_remaining=False)
```

Output:

```
             col1
idx1    idx2    
1       C    105
        B    102
        A    99
        D    97
2       A    19
        D    17
        B    14
        C    10
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with a groupby (the already existing indexes) and an apply:

```
df.groupby(level=[0]).apply(lambda x:x.groupby(level=[1]).sum().sort_values('col1',ascending=False))
```

Output:

```
           col1
idx1 idx2      
1    C      105
     B      102
     A       99
     D       97
2    A       19
     D       17
     B       14
     C       10
```