# Extracting the head of a group based on MultiIndex in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371308/sort-by-column-within-multi-index-level-in-pandas) which demonstrates how to sort a `DataFrame` based on the first level of a MultiIndex.  So an initial DataFrame that looks like

```
l = [[1,'A',99],[1,'B',102],[1,'C',105],[1,'D',97],[2,'A',19],[2,'B',14],[2,'C',10],[2,'D',17]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns = ['idx1','idx2','col1'])
df.set_index(['idx1','idx2'],inplace=True)

# assume data has been received like this...
print df

           col1
idx1 idx2      
1    A       99
     B      102
     C      105
     D       97
2    A       19
     B       14
     C       10
     D       17
```

Can be sorted within each `level=1` group to produce:

```
           col1
idx1 idx2      
1    C      105
     B      102
     A       99
     D       97

2    A       19
     D       17
     B       14
     C       10
```

My question is: **how can I extract the first `n` elements of each group based on the first level?**

For example, if `n=2` then the result would be:

```
           col1
idx1 idx2      
1    C      105
     B      102

2    A       19
     D       17
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need `head` on `groupby` of the sorted dataframe:

```
df.sort_values('col1', ascending=False).groupby('idx1').head(2)
```

Output:

```
           col1
idx1 idx2      
1    C      105
     B      102
2    A       19
     D       17
```