# Sort index using both level and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with two levels of index and with some columns, say 'A', 'B' which store `float` values. I would like to sort index of this `DataFrame` in such a way that level 1 is sorted alphabetially (so I can use `df.sort_index(level = 0)`) but the second level should be sorted decreasing depending on the value of 'A' column (here I can use `df.sort_values("A")`. How can I combine these two types of sorting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Does this answer your question?  [Sort by column within multi index level in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371308/sort-by-column-within-multi-index-level-in-pandas)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you want. It might be helpful if you provided an example input and desired output. If you wish to organize A and B so that the data is organized first by A increasing and then by B decreasing, you can use df.sort_values(by=["A","B"],ascending=["True","False"]). See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: example of the data would be helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example